# Is there a way to use hyperlink from within draw.io - offline desktop app

Tags: configuration, diagram, confluence, add-on, draw.io

Is there a way to include a hyperlink from the text in one of the draw.io objects? This would help to link from the diagram to relevant Confluence pages.

Using "Edit->Edit Link" works only by inserting a URL. I would like to open another saved xml.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the [Draw.io add-on](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.mxgraph.confluence.plugins.diagramly/cloud/overview) (the cloud version is free) from the Confluence Marketplace for about 2 or 3 days in the last 2 weeks and added a few flowcharts where certain chart steps were linking to how-to articles in Confluence and the flowchart itself was used in the troubleshooting pages. I can't remember exactly how I added the links into the diagrams but as I can remember there was an "insert link" feature which can be used on certain selected diagram objects.

I wasn't happy with draw.io's visualization methods and their feature-set was very limited. Nowadays I'm evaluating [Lucidcharts](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.lucidchart.confluence.plugins.lucid-confluence/cloud/overview) and it looks very promising. Their linking process is a bit different than draw.io which is a little bit cumbersome but they deliver much more feats in a much more powerful visualization. (And yes their Confluence cloud add-on is not free!)